# OpenGL: question about super / self

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es

I just started trying out a book of OpenGL out of personal interest and bumped into the following code:

```
@implementation GLView

+(Class) layerClass {

// This method returns the CALayer class object by default. Subclasses can override this method and return a different layer class as needed. For example, if you use OpenGL ES to do your drawing, you would override this method and return the class object for the CAEAGLLayer class.

return [CAEAGLLayer class];

}

-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {

if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

    CAEAGLLayer* eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) super.layer;
    eaglLayer.opaque = YES;

    m_context = [[EAGLContext alloc]initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

    if(!m_context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context]) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I try to understand every step along the way and I have two primary question in this piece of code already. 
What is the difference if we use here: "self.layer" instead of "super.layer"? 
The current class (in the example called "GLView") inherits from UIView; why would we call the super and could it in fact make any difference?

Second, I don't understand why se must release "self" instead of "m_context" here, since it's the context that's being allocated memory. 
Thanks for your replies and sorry for any stupid questions!

Comment: If you're interested in where I got the code from. Check:O'reilly iPhone 3D Porgramming. You can download it from www.wowebook.com.

Comment: This is not related to OpenGL directly, but to the Objective-C language (which uses OpenGL).

Comment: So in other words, if you want to understand this code, you'll have to learn Objective-C. Note that OpenGL can be used with other languages. Best way will be to find C examples, so you can understand the basics, and then apply them to other languages, or supersets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Macmade. I understand what you mean. I did read the basic documentation though and the concepts are pretty clear. Despite, I wanted a confirmation if I could use "self" in this specific case as well; since I'm not that experienced, I didn't know if that would make any difference. As for the "self release", Kornel answered accurately; it's a lack of experience that makes me doubt sometimes but it will come. Thanks and greetings!

Comment: Good luck for you projects : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General answer -- this is a really bad example for learning to code, because this specific book mixes C++ and Objective-C -- many things get really messy and complicated in such a situation.

Specific answers:

1. `self` is the class that the method is a part of, `super` is the class that the `self` inherits from
2. we're freeing `self`, because we had an unrecoverable failure -- so we don't need neither the context, nor anything else.

Comment: Oh, you know the book :-) Still, I'll try to struggle through because I really want to learn this stuff. Ok for the release of self > that makes perfect sense. And if I understand your reply well, it doesn't really matter if I use self or super in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @user917467: you're right that it shouldn't make any difference, since `release` will call `dealloc` if an object is actually deallocated, at which point any overridden implementation you may have supplied will be called regardless. Normally though you'd use `super` only when there's a specific reason to do so and `self` as a matter of routine, so it'd be `self` in this case. Also, you use `[self release]` rather than releasing everything created up to that point because that's a safe way to ensure everything is released no matter where you are in the init, making it idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks Tommy, that is a very useful and specific explanation. I also thought that using "self" would be more logical; they don't explain it like this in the books. About the [self release]; I've released objects when I took ownership in the way the theory explained up till now (when using alloc, retain, copy, ...). And by the way, Kornel is right. The book kinda sucks; I need to look up everything on the internet to get a proper explanation. On the other hand, it's not a bad way to go; then I need to check out everything at once.